TWRP: Failed to mount '/rca' (invalid argument)
I just installed LineageOS 18 on a Sony Xperia X Compact. It was working fine except that I could not download apps from Play Store (they always stay on pending).
I saw a guy on the internet who said that after a factory reset, it was working. I did so in LineageOS and now I have this problem: The phone always boots on TWRP, and when I try to wipe or re-install the custom ROM, it says:

Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/rca' (invalid argument)

I saw a lot of posts like mine but never with "rca".
I don't know what it is and I don't know what I should do.
